# moving elements of an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays as following .I am using C language

```
    int array1[7][8];
    int array2[8][7];
```

all elemnts of array 1 have some values

I want to assign all values of array 1 to array 2 . Because both arrays have total 56 elements.Values should be able to fit.I want to assign all 56 values of array 1 to array 2 such that if they are seen as 1 dimensional array then they should look identical 
I tried to iterate through a loop from 0 to 56 and tried to relate their indexes but was unable to figure out.
I tried something like this but i am mistaking somewhere

```
  for (i = 0 ; i < 56 ; i ++)
  {
            array2[i / 7 ][ i % 7 ] = array1[ i / 6 ][ i % 6];
  }
```

Comment: What do you want in `array2[5][0]`? Isn't it `array1[0][5]`? Or, more generally: you want to put in `array2[row][col]` what is `array1[col][row]`

Comment: @pmg oops you realized me i explained it wrong i want all 56 elements in the second array like if you see both arrays as one dimensional then they are identical

Comment: Then ignore the dimensions and `memmove()` the data around. `memove(array2, array1, sizeof array1);`

Comment: @pmg would I be able to access array 2 later as 2 dimensional

Comment: I've made an expanded answer out of that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not a transposition of the array elements!**

Ignore the dimensions and `memmove()` the data around.

```
memmove(array2, array1, sizeof array1);
```

`memmove()` doesn't care about the layout of the array elements and the Standard guarantees all array elements (even of multi-dimensional arrays) are sequential.

Answer (score 2):

Use two loops:

```
for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++)
{
   for ( size_t j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++)
   {
        array2[j][i] = array1[i][j];
   }
}
```

And with a single loop:

```
for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < 56 ; i++ )
{
    array2[i / 7 ][ i % 7 ] = array1[ i / 8 ][ i % 8 ] ;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It shall be

```
for (i = 0; i < 7*8; ++i)
{
  array2[i / 7][i % 7] = array1[i / 8][i % 8];
}
```